# passing locals array from Express to Javascript

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using Jade and

```
- if (userId !== null)
  != "<script type='text/javascript'>"
  != "userDetail.userId = "+userId.toString()+";"
  - if (friends && friends.length > 0)
    != "userDetail.friends = "+friends+";"
  != "</script>"
```

In Javascript, userDetail.js,

```
var userDetail = {};

userDetail.userId = null;
userDetail.friends = [];
```

When I run this I get  - `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

I am able to refer to userDetail.userId in JS, but userDetail.friends appears as null.
Any clue what's wrong ?

friends is an array of object {id, name, _id}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `JSON.stringify(friends)` as opposed to the default `friends.toString()` that you have.

```
node
> [{id: 42, name: "ray"}].toString()
'[object Object]'
> JSON.stringify([{id: 42, name: "ray"}])
'[{"id":42,"name":"ray"}]'
```

Comment: Thanks much. Your example is also perfect for the explanation.